# Jquery on click works on one page doesn't work on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, craftcms

dropdown click working on one page but not on another even though its the same component that these page load and same javaScript file

Here's the component

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Please Select A Fabric Range</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {% for fabricRange in fabricRanges %}
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" id="tab-{{ fabricRange.id }}" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#tabpane{{fabricRange.id}}" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tabpane-{{fabricRange.id}}" aria-selected="true">{{fabricRange.title}}</a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
```

And JS

```
 $(".dropdown-menu").on("click", "a.nav-link.dropdown-item", function() {
    console.log("clicked")
    $(this).parents(".nav-item.dropdown").find("a.dropdown-toggle").html($(this).html())
})
```

I have used it in three pages, two works, one doesn't.
the console.log() also works fine on the two pages but no response in third.  Please Help

Comment: hi, perhaps step through in the debugger to see if the selector is working as expected on that page

Comment: @jspcal no it's just doesn't respond to this click at all.

Comment: Assuming you have some elements that match `a.nav-link.dropdown-item` inside `.dropdown-menu` on the third page, I guess `.dropdown-menu` didn't exist when you ran the code to assign the click listener.  Are you loading the JS file in the same place on each page?

Comment: @James You were right, it's not just me who is coding in this project, but moving around the jquery part solved it for me, Thanks.
Will you post an answer so I could upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you need to verify whether dropdown-menu class exists or not. In case if it exists then you need to check whether it has nav-link dropdown-item class or not.
   So for this you need to check HTML of that element. Please follow below piece of code for this purpose.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var count = 0;
   if ($(".dropdown-menu").length > 0) {
       $(".dropdown-menu").each(function(index, item) {
           count = count + 1;
           if(count !== 0){
               console.log($(item).html());
               console.log(item.innerHTML);
           }
       }); 
   }
   //alert("count-->"+count);
   console.log(count);})
   ```
2. After verification, if you've everything mention in point 1 above and still click is not working then you have to verify if
   JQUERY is getting loaded correctly and in the same hierarchy as on other 2 pages.

Comment: The page i was struggling with was not loaded on documeent.ready is my guess, so i moved around it a bit, placed it in 2 different files for different component it works now,

Thanks for looking into it.